# React-intl define messages outside of react

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I have utils.js file.

```
export function categoryIdToCategoryName(categoryId) {
let name;
switch (categoryId) {
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_LOW:
        name = 'low';
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_MEDIUM:
        name = 'medium';
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_HIGH:
        name = 'high';
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_CRITICAL:
        name = 'critical';
        break;
    default:
        console.warn('see: /utils/risk.js', 'categoryIdToCategoryName:', categoryId);
        name = 'unknown';
   }
    return name;
}
```

I would like to translate this texts - [low, medium, high, critical] using https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl. So I defined messages

```
const translations = defineMessages({
riskLow: {
    id: 'utils.risk.low',
    defaultMessage: 'low',
},
riskMedium: {
    id: 'utils.risk.medium',
    defaultMessage: 'medium',
},
riskHigh: {
    id: 'utils.risk.high',
    defaultMessage: 'high',
},
riskCritical: {
    id: 'utils.risk.critical',
    defaultMessage: 'critical',
}
});
```

And now what is the last step?

How can I pass the messages back to the function? There should be `formatMessage` function but it's only in react context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think in your case you want to have access to the `intl` object but this file is not a react component, right?
If it is the case, you'd have to create a provider inside this file, something similar to what you probably already have in your index.js file.

In your `utils.js` file you'd add this:

```
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import localeDataEN from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';

addLocaleData(localeDataEN);
const locale = 'en'
const messages = //read it from your translated json file
const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ locale, messages });
const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext(); // this is how you get access to the formatMessage function to use i18n for your messages

function categoryIdToCategoryName(categoryId) {
let name;
switch (categoryId) {
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_LOW:
        name = intl.formatMessage(formMessages.riskLow);
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_MEDIUM:
        name = intl.formatMessage(formMessages.riskMedium);
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_HIGH:
        name = intl.formatMessage(formMessages.riskHigh);
        break;
    case constants.RISK_CATEGORY_CRITICAL:
        name = intl.formatMessage(formMessages.riskCritical);
        break;
    default:
        console.warn('see: /utils/risk.js', 'categoryIdToCategoryName:', categoryId);
        name = 'unknown';
   }
    return name;
}
```

You can also check this answer: [React-intl for non components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785313/react-intl-for-non-components/50170516#50170516)

Comment: `translations` is never used

Answer (score 10):

It can now be done with the [CreateIntl](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#createintl) API (version 4.6.4 React-intl)

Here is a code snippet that is working for me :

```
import { createIntl, createIntlCache } from 'react-intl';
import English from '../../translations/en-US.json'; //your messages translated with id

const cache = createIntlCache();
const intl = createIntl({ locale: 'en-US', messages: English, }, cache);//locale and message can come from Redux or regular import
const number = intl.formatNumber(2000); //just use imperative way like you would with useIntl() hook or InjectIntl HOC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use the yahoo intl library for this task: https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat

Otherwise you can pass the `formatMessage` function from your react component to the functions it calls.