# React-intl for non components

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Currently I have the following code to expose react-intl to non-components, but it throws an error for intl as undefined.

I have created a separate component as 'CurrentLocale' and inject-intl to it. The exporting function t will use intl formatMessage from CurrentLocale context.

```
import React from 'react';
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { flow } from 'lodash';

class CurrentLocale extends React.Component {


    constructor(props,context){

        super();
        console.log(context,props);
        console.log(this.formatMessage);
        const { intl } = this.context.intl;//this.props;

        this.formatMessage = intl.formatMessage;
    }

    render() {
        return false;
    }
}
CurrentLocale.contextTypes={
    intl:PropTypes.object,
};


injectIntl(CurrentLocale);

function intl() {
    return new CurrentLocale();
}

function formatMessage(...args) {
    return intl().formatMessage(...args);
}


const t = opts => {
    const id = opts.id;
    const type = opts.type;
    const values = opts.values;
    let t;

    switch (type){

        case 'message':
        default:
            t = formatMessage(id, values);
    }

    return t;
}

export default t;
```

t is called as in another plain javascript file as,

```
import t from './locale/t';
t( { type: 'message', id:'button.Next'});
```

Following is the error message.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `intl.get('key')`, it returns a translated string. see [react-intl examples](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `const { intl } = this.context.intl;` should be `const { intl } = this.context;`

Here is a reference post of someone doing almost the exact same thing as you are: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/983#issuecomment-342314143

In the above the author is creating essentially a singleton that is exported instead of creating a new instance each time like you have above. This might be something you want to consider as well.

Answer (score 16):

There's also another approach very simple I used for solving a similar problem: Provide access to the `intl` object for a non-component:

```
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import localeDataDE from 'react-intl/locale-data/de';
import localeDataEN from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
import { formMessages } from '../../../store/i18n'; // I defined some messages here
import { Locale } from '../../../../utils'; //I set the locale fom here

addLocaleData([...localeDataEN, ...localeDataDE]);
const locale = Locale.setLocale(); //my own methods to retrieve locale
const messages = Locale.setMessages(); //getting messages from the json file.
const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ locale, messages });
const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();

export const SCHEMA = {
  salutation: {
    label: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.salutationLabel),
    errormessages: {
      required: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.salutationError),
    },
  },
  academic_title_code: {
    label: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.academicTitleLabel),
  },
};
```

It's working like a charm!

> **UPDATE for v3.x**

[After migration to react-intl 3.x](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Upgrade-Guide.md#creating-intl-without-using-provider)

```
import { createIntl, createIntlCache } from 'react-intl'
import { formMessages } from '../../../store/i18n'; // I defined some messages here
import { Locale } from '../../../../utils'; //I set the locale fom here

const locale = Locale.setLocale(); //my own methods to retrieve locale
const messages = Locale.setMessages(); //getting messages from the json file.
// This is optional but highly recommended
// since it prevents memory leak
const cache = createIntlCache();
const intl = createIntl({ locale, messages }, cache)

export const SCHEMA = {
  salutation: {
    label: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.salutationLabel),
    errormessages: {
      required: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.salutationError),
    },
  },
  academic_title_code: {
    label: intl.formatMessage(formMessages.academicTitleLabel),
  },
};
```

Comment: In the new version of react-intl, this solution result in error which says `.getChildContext is not a function`.

Comment: I update my libs once a month and will probably have this issue then next week when I do that. but last time I checked (last month), with 2.9.0 it works. Thanks for pointing the issue. I'll keep an eye on it once I update it as I use it A LOT and probably it might break my application.

Answer (score 7):

There's a new way to do it pretty easily with `createIntl`, it returns an object that you can use outside React components. Here's an example from the [documentation](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api#createintl).

```
import {createIntl, createIntlCache, RawIntlProvider} from 'react-intl'

// This is optional but highly recommended
// since it prevents memory leak
const cache = createIntlCache()

const intl = createIntl({
  locale: 'fr-FR',
  messages: {}
}, cache)

// Call imperatively
intl.formatNumber(20)

// Pass it to IntlProvider
<RawIntlProvider value={intl}>{foo}</RawIntlProvider>
```

I personally store the `intl` object in Redux store so I can access it everywhere in my app.

Comment: doesn't it impact in your application's bundle size?

Comment: you cant actually update this in the run time through store or local storage or even button click. Need to hook it to something to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another way solving a similar problem to used react-intl **formatMessage** for non-components.

Create a **LocaleStore.js** store file.

```
 import _formatMessage from "format-message";

    export default class LocaleStore {

      formatMessage = (id, values) => {
        if (!(id in this.messages)) {
          console.warn("Id not found in intl list: " + id);
          return id;
        }
        return _formatMessage(this.messages[id], values);
      };
    }
```

import LocaleStore your **CombinedStores.js**

```
import LocaleStore from "./stores/LocaleStore";
import en from "./translations/en";
import de from "./translations/de";
import Global from "./stores/global"
const locale = new LocaleStore("en", {
  en,
  de
});
export default {
global:new Global(locale) 
}
```

now you can use this in your **GlobalStore.js**

```
    class GlobalStore {
    constructor(locale) {
     this.locale = locale;
    }

   formatMessage=(message_is,formatLanguage="en")=> {
     return  this.locale.formatMessage(message_id, formatLanguage);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-intl` decorates your React.Component with wrapped component which is injected internationalized message dynamically so that the locale data is able to be loaded dynamically.

```
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const intl = this.props;
    const title = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'title' });
    return (<div>{title}</div>);
  }
};
export default injectIntl(MyComponent);
```

It can be applied only in view layer such as React.Component.
`react-intl` can't be used in Vanilla JS. For example,

```js
export default const rules = {
  noSpace(value) {
    if (value.includes(' ')) {
      return 'Space is not allowed.';
    }
  }
};
```

One of alternative is [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal). It can be used not only in Component but also in Vanilla JS.

For example:

```js
import intl from 'react-intl-universal';
export default const rules = {
  noSpace(value) {
    if (value.includes(' ')) {
      return intl.get('no_space');
    }
  }
};
```

See [react-intl-universal online example](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal)

Answer (score -2):

If you can accept to use a function component I prefer to use the `useIntl hook`

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

I can then get values like this:

```
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";

const intl = useIntl()
intl.formatMessage({ id: 'myId' }),
```

https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#useintl-hook

Comment: If you vote down please say why! Very hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It can be only used inside the react component

Comment: @LabLab Very true, I will update my answer with clarification.